# AWS Redshift - Identity Field Syntax

Tags: amazon-redshift

What does this Redshift Identity field creation syntax mean:

`idfield int DEFAULT "identity"(6035942, 0, ('1,1'::character varying)::text) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030963/signature-of-the-redshift-internal-identity-function)

It will create an INT column named idfield which will get autopopulated with a numeric sequence starting at 1, and incrementing by 1 for every new record. "Autopopulated" means you don't have to specify that column in any INSERT statement: it will automatically get a new value.

A simpler syntax would be `idfield int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks @Schepo. Yes, I understood that this is an Identity column. But couldn't understand the syntax. The Link you have provided has answered the question.